# VS code extension: How to get line number for a regex in editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to develop a Visual Code extension which matches for a certain Regex in the editor. I want to show each match with `window.showInputBox` so that the user can select one and I want to navigate to the corresponding line in the editor.

How can I get the line number for my matches? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but it kind of sounds like you might want to implement a SymbolProvider, see e.g.: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_show-all-symbol-definitions-within-a-document

Comment: @UnholySheep: Thanks for the answer but I found a simpler solution as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Mojo May I know your answer? It isn't visible

Comment: @RaamakrishnanA. Sure, I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
function getTests(document: TextDocument): Promise<Test[]> {
  // Return a promise, since this might take a while for large documents
  return new Promise<Test[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    let testsToReturn = new Array<Test>();
    let lineCount = document.lineCount;

    for (let lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < lineCount; lineNumber++) {
      let lineText = document.lineAt(lineNumber);
      let tests = lineText.text.match(/(it\(|describe\()/g);
      if (tests) {
        for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
          testsToReturn.push({ lineText: lineText });
        }
      }
    }
    if (testsToReturn.length > 0) {
      resolve(testsToReturn);
    } else {
      reject('Found no tests');
    }
  }).catch();
}
```

The line number is then available in the returned `Test` object via

```
test.lineText.lineNumber
```

See [full source code](https://github.com/Mokkapps/jasmine-test-selector/blob/master/src/extension.ts) for more details.